# SVG viewport size not respected in IE

Tags: html, internet-explorer, svg

I have a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mihaifm/ceUTx/1/) for this.
The below SVG is not rendered correctly in IE9. The transformed text goes over the viewport size, unlike in all the other browsers.

Any ideas/workarounds ?

thanks

```
<div>
   <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="400px" height="200px">
        <g width="400px" height="200px" transform="matrix(4,0,0,4,-1134,-491)">
            <text x="352" y="179.5" fill="#fff700" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="1" 
                  font-family="Arial" font-size="30" font-weight="bold" 
                  font-style="normal" transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,0,0)">
                  AAA
            </text>
        </g>
        <rect x="0" y="0" width="400px" height="200px" 
              fill="none" stroke="black" stroke-width="1">
        </rect>
    </svg>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolved with:

```
overflow: 'hidden'
```

It's probably the default in the other browsers, but not in IE.

Comment: Not sure if the case is the same, but this helped me where in IE11 an inline SVG element that seemed to have the correct dimensions still made horizontal and vertical scroll bars appear on the page, despite no contents of it visibly overflowing.